# ret instruction causes segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I have written a program in assembly that is not working. It is an assembly implementation of the seq utility. Actually, I have written only a part of that.

This is the assembly code:

```
/* -- seq.S -- */
#include <asm/unistd_64.h>
#include <asm/errno.h>

#define LAST_ERR    "LAST must be a non-negative integer"
#define FIRST_ERR   "FIRST must be a non-negative integer"
#define INCREMENT_ERR   "INCREMENT must be a positive integer"

#define EXIT \
    mov     $60, %rax; \
    syscall

#ifdef DEBUG
.DEBUG_INT:
    .asciz  "%c"
#define PRINTCHAR(int) \
    xor     %rdi, %rdi; \
    movb    int, %dil; \
    mov     $.DEBUG_INT, %rsi; \
    xor     %al, %al; \
    call    errx
#endif
    
#define XSTRTOL(nptr, msg, out) \
    movq    nptr, %rdi;         \
    movq    msg, %rsi;          \
    call    xstrtol;            \
    movq    %rax, out;
    
    .text

/* -- main -- */
    .global main
main:
    movl    %edi, %r14d
    movq    %rsi, %r15
    mov     $.LC0, %rdx
    call    getopt
    cmpl    $-1, %eax
    jne     usage
    movl    optind(%rip), %eax
    subl    %eax, %r14d
    cltq
    leaq    0(%r15, %rax, 8), %r15
    cmp     $1, %r14d
    je      .L0
    cmp     $2, %r14d
    je      .L1
    cmp     $3, %r14d
    jne usage
    /* 3 */
    XSTRTOL((%r15), $.LC2, %r12)
    XSTRTOL(8(%r15), $.LC3, %r13)
    XSTRTOL(16(%r15), $.LC4, %r14)

.L0:
    /* 1 */
    XSTRTOL((%r15), $.LC4, %r14)
    EXIT
    movq    $1, %r12
    movq    $1, %r13
.L1:
    /* 2 */
    XSTRTOL((%r15), $.LC2, %r12)
    XSTRTOL(8(%r15), $.LC4, %r14)
    movq    $1, %r13
/* -- main END -- */

/* -- xstrtol -- */
.LC1:
    .asciz "%s"
xstrtol:
    subq    $32, %rsp      /* -32 */
    movq    %rbx, 32(%rsp) /* saving */
    movq    %rsi, 24(%rsp) /* saving */
    movq    %rdi, 16(%rsp) /* saving */
    call    __errno_location
    movq    %rax, %rbx
    movl    $0, (%rax)
    movq    16(%rsp), %rdi
    leaq    8(%rsp), %rsi
    movl    $10, %edx
    call    strtol
    cmpl    $ERANGE, (%rbx)
    je      .L3
    movq    8(%rsp), %rdx
    cmpb    $0, (%rdx)
    jne     .L4
    movq    32(%rsp), %rbx
    addq    $32, %rsp       /* +0 */
    ret
.L3:                        /* __dead_start */
    movl    $1, %edi
    movq    $.LC1, %rsi
    movq    16(%rsp), %rdx
    xorb    %al, %al
    call    err             /* __dead_end */
.L4:                        /* __dead_start */
    movl    $1, %edi
    movq    16(%rsp), %rsi
    xorb    %al, %al
    call    errx            /* __dead_end */
/* -- xstrtol END -- */

usage:
    mov     stderr(%rip), %rdi
    mov     $.LC5, %rsi
    mov     __progname(%rip), %rdx
    mov     %rdx, %rcx
    mov     %rdx, %r8
    xor     %al, %al
    call    fprintf
    mov     $1, %rbx
exit:
    mov     $__NR_exit, %rax
    syscall

.LC0:
    .asciz ""
.LC4:
    .asciz LAST_ERR
.LC2:
    .asciz FIRST_ERR
.LC3:
    .asciz INCREMENT_ERR
.LC5:
    .asciz "usage: %s LAST\n       %s FIRST LAST\n       %s FIRST INCREMENT LAST\n"
```

The only problem I have is that, whenever xstrtol is called, the last ret gives segmentation fault. BUT, if I comment   addq    $32, %rsp and subq  $32, %rsp it works fine.
My question is: why does it behave like this?

If it can be of any help, this is the corresponding C code:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define LAST_ERR    "LAST must be a non-negative integer"
#define FIRST_ERR   "FIRST must be a non-negative integer"
#define INCREMENT_ERR   "INCREMENT must be a positive integer"

/* Get the length of umber if it were a string
 * num: number to get the length of
 */
static size_t
numlen(long num)
{
    size_t len = 0;

    do {
        len++;
        num /= 10;
    } while (num > 0);

    return len;
}
        
/* Convert to long or die.
 * @nptr: pointer to the number in string format
 * @msg: message to be displayed in case of death.
 */
static long
xstrtol(char *nptr, char *msg)
{
    long rv;
    char *buf;

    errno = 0;
    rv = strtol(nptr, &buf, 10);
    if (errno == ERANGE)
        err(1, "strtol");
    if (*buf != '\0')
        errx(1, msg);
    
    return rv;
}

void
usage(int exitcode)
{
    extern const char *__progname;
    fprintf(stderr,
        "usage: %s LAST\n"
        "       %s FIRST LAST\n"
        "       %s FIRST INCREMENT LAST\n",
     __progname, __progname, __progname);

    exit(exitcode);
}


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rv = 0;
    int first = 1;
    int last;
    int increment = 1;
    char *buf;
    size_t first_len;
    ssize_t nw;
    int ch;
    
    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "")) != -1)
        switch (ch) {
        default:
            usage(1);
        }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    switch (argc) {
    case 1:
        last = xstrtol(argv[0], LAST_ERR);
        break;
    case 2:
        first = xstrtol(argv[0], FIRST_ERR);
        last  = xstrtol(argv[1], LAST_ERR);
        break;
    case 3:
        first     = xstrtol(argv[0], FIRST_ERR);
        increment = xstrtol(argv[1], INCREMENT_ERR);
        last      = xstrtol(argv[2], LAST_ERR);
        break;
    default:
        usage(1);
    }

    if (first < 0)
        errx(1, FIRST_ERR);
    if (last < 0)
        errx(1, LAST_ERR);
    if (increment <= 0)
        errx(1, INCREMENT_ERR);
    if (first > last)
        errx(1, "FIRST must be greater or equal than LAST");

    for (; first <= last; first += increment) {
        first_len = numlen(first);
        buf = (char *)malloc((first_len+1) * sizeof(char));
        if (buf == NULL)
            err(1, NULL);
        for (int i = 0; i < first_len; i++)
            buf[first_len-1-i] = (int)(first/pow(10, i)) % 10 + '0';
        buf[first_len++] = ' ';
        while ((nw = write(fileno(stdout), buf, first_len)) > 0) {
            first_len -= nw;
            buf     += nw;
        }
        if (nw == -1) {
            warn("stdout");
            rv = 1;
        }
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: You need to allocate more than 32 bytes on the stack.  If you subtract 32 from `rsp`, then `32(%rsp)` points at the return address.  Try subtracting 40 or 48 from `rsp`.

Comment: Or save registers with `push` instead of `mov` so stack space for them gets reserved implicitly.